# How to close notification when user clicks on it

Tags: android, notifications

I'm having difficulties closing my notification once a user clicks on it from the notification bar. I'm aware of the setAutoCancel method but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my code nevertheless.

**MondayNotificationService.class**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        builder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name));

    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("FirstPeriod")) {
        builder.setContentText("Microwave Engineering");
        builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, new Intent(context, Monday.class), 0));
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        int notificationID = 100;
        notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notification);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        long delayInMilliseconds = 300000;
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                notificationManager.cancel(100);
            }
        }, delayInMilliseconds);

    } if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("SecondPeriod")) {
        builder.setContentText("Digital Signal Processing");
        builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 101, new Intent(context, Monday.class), 0));
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        int notificationID = 101;
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notification);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        long delayInMilliseconds = 300000;
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                notificationManager.cancel(101);
            }
        }, delayInMilliseconds);
    }
```

**Monday.class**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_monday);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent firstIntent = new Intent(this, MondayNotificationService.class);
    firstIntent.setAction("FirstPeriod");
    PendingIntent firstAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, firstIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    calendar.set(2016, 3, 23, 20, 40, 0);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), firstAlarmIntent);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, firstAlarmIntent);

    Intent secondIntent = new Intent(this, MondayNotificationService.class);
    secondIntent.setAction("SecondPeriod");
    PendingIntent secondAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 101, secondIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    calendar.set(2016, 3, 23, 20, 12, 0);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), secondAlarmIntent);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, secondAlarmIntent);
```

Also when the notification expires after 5 minutes, and I open the app and click on the "Monday" button then all the notifications are displayed in the notification bar right away (even the expired ones).
Any help in understanding what is going wrong will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: You need to call `setAutoCancel()` before you `build()` the `Notification`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mike M. points out, you need to configure the `Builder` before calling `build()`.

You have:

```
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
```

Reverse those lines:

```
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    Notification notification = builder.build();
```

Comment: The method specified by you seems to be working, but the problem is that whenever I click on the button of my app, all the notifications are issued simultaneously. Any fix on that?

Comment: @SiddharthSaxena: Well, you are setting two alarms to go off two months ago (23 March 2016). Try picking a time in the future. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL`

As per the documentation

> Bit to be bitwise-ored into the flags field that should be set if the notification should be canceled when it is clicked by the user